# High mySQL cpu usage

Tags: mysql, load

Our mySQL server is at most of the time running at a extremly high load.
We have no idea where it's comming from.

As you can see:

```
 589    admin       localhost   psa     Sleep
1440    gwingocm    localhost   gwingo  Sleep
1442    gwingocm    localhost   gwingo  Sleep
1441    amfbcm      localhost   amfb    Sleep
1444    gwingocm    localhost   gwingo  Sleep
1446    gwingocm    localhost   gwingo  Sleep
1447    gwingocm    localhost   gwingo  Sleep
1448    gwingocm    localhost   gwingo  Sleep
1449    amfbcm      localhost   amfb    Sleep
1450    amfbcm      localhost   amfb    Sleep
1498    admin       localhost   mysql   Query
```

This was the proccesslist at a time that the usage was really high.

Any one a good idea how to find out the problem?

Best regards,
Tim

Comment: What query was `admin@localhost` running on the `mysql` schema?

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` will tell you what is the query

Comment: I did the SHOW ENGINE INNODB:

This was the result:
=====================================
120728 12:3...

The Admin was the login of PLESK, and  phpmyadmin.